# Ajax con un if anidado no funciona

Tags: jquery, ajax

Si obtiene en 'acro_proyecto' el dato 'SPD' que haga una función si este no es recibido que realice otra:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

if(acro_proyecto == 'SPD')
   $('#titulo_documento, #compania1, #acro_subcategoria, #acro_proyecto, #datepicker, #idioma, #acro_documento, #proyecto, #estado, #num_documento, \n\
    #version, #revision, #descripcion, #confidencialidad, #acro_usuario1, #aprobado_por1, #autorizado_por1, #revisor1').blur(function () {
   $('#codigo_proyecto').val($('#compania1').val() + "-" + $('#acro_subcategoria').val() + "-" + $('#acro_documento').val() + $('#num_documento').val() + "");
            });
else
   $('#titulo_documento, #compania1, #acro_subcategoria, #acro_proyecto, #datepicker, #idioma, #acro_documento, #proyecto, #estado, #num_documento, \n\
    #version, #revision, #descripcion, #confidencialidad, #acro_usuario1, #aprobado_por1, #autorizado_por1, #revisor1').blur(function () {
   $('#codigo_proyecto').val($('#acro_proyecto').val() + "-" + $('#compania1').val() + "-" + $('#acro_subcategoria').val() + "-" + $('#acro_documento').val() + $('#num_documento').val() + "");
            });
        });
```

'acro_proyecto lo recoge de un selector:

```
<td>
   <select class="form-control" name="acro_proyecto" id="acro_proyecto"  onchange="change_documento1();  change_documento2();" >
          <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('proyecto') : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('proyecto') : ''; ?> </option> 
               <?php
               $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dmsgeneratorcode', 'root', '');
               $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
               $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select acro_proyecto from proyectos order by acro_proyecto');
               $stmt->execute();
               while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                        echo '<option>' . $row['acro_proyecto'] . '</option>';
                }
                ?>
        </select>
 </td>
```

Comment: Podrías especificar un poco mas la pregunta y colocar el resto del código html y javascript

Comment: Es que son como unas míl líneas. lo intentare explicar un poco mejor.

Comment: Amigo especifica bien lo que deseas hacer y el código involucrado, por que a simple vista tu caso se podría solucionar con un if, saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se debe de cambiar a una función en este caso 'change' que pueda activarla y la 'ID' del campo debe de ir seleccionada en tipo 'ajax' que para eso es el tipo de lenguaje que se esta utilizando y funciona perfectamente ahora:

```
            function change_documento9() {

            if($('#acro_proyecto').val() == "SPD")
            $('#titulo_documento, #compania1, #acro_subcategoria, #acro_proyecto, #datepicker, #idioma, #acro_documento, #proyecto, #estado, #num_documento, \n\
    #version, #revision, #descripcion, #confidencialidad, #acro_usuario1, #aprobado_por1, #autorizado_por1, #revisor1').blur(function () {
                $('#codigo_proyecto').val($('#compania1').val() + "-" + $('#acro_subcategoria').val() + "-" + $('#acro_documento').val() + $('#num_documento').val() + "");
            });
    else
        $('#titulo_documento, #compania1, #acro_subcategoria, #acro_proyecto, #datepicker, #idioma, #acro_documento, #proyecto, #estado, #num_documento, \n\
    #version, #revision, #descripcion, #confidencialidad, #acro_usuario1, #aprobado_por1, #autorizado_por1, #revisor1').blur(function () {
                $('#codigo_proyecto').val($('#acro_proyecto').val() + "-" + $('#compania1').val() + "-" + $('#acro_subcategoria').val() + "-" + $('#acro_documento').val() + $('#num_documento').val() + "");
            });
        };
```